# git-http-backend, ro for all, write requiring password? (with lighttpd)

Tags: git, trac

I'd like to offer up read-only access to my GIT repos for everyone (i.e. no username/password required), but require authentication for writing.  The [`git-http-backend` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) suggests this is possible by matching against the location `^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$`.  For Apache 2.x it'd look like this:

```
<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Access"
    Require group committers
    ...
</LocationMatch>
```

Now, I'm using lighttpd, but translating the above shouldn't cause a problem.  Except that my access log suggests that the above wouldn't work anyway.  This is what I see when I perform a `git push`:

```
192.168.1.84 tracsrv.local - [06/Apr/2013:20:00:20 +0200] "GET /git/foo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 403 5 "-" "git/1.8.2"
```

So it looks like I need to match on the query string.  For lighty I tried this:

```
$HTTP["querystring"] =~ "service=git-receive-pack" {
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/git" {
        cgi.assign = ( "" => "" )
        setenv.add-environment = (
            "GIT_PROJECT_ROOT" => "/srv/git",
            "GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL" => ""
        )

        auth.backend = "plain"
        auth.backend.plain.userfile = "/srv/tracprjs/trac.plain"
        auth.require = (
            "/" => (
                "method" => "basic",
                "realm" => "trac",
                "require" => "valid-user"
                )
            )
    }
}

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/git" {
    cgi.assign = ( "" => "" )
    setenv.add-environment = (
        "GIT_PROJECT_ROOT" => "/srv/git",
        "GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL" => ""
    )
}
```

No password is required for `git fetch` and it is required for `git push`.  However, the `git push` doesn't actually succeed.  Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working configuration with the help of the people on the git mailing list: http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg203744.html